# How to convert textbox year date value to check if it has only 2 digits?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The problem that I have is related to only being possible to insert 2 digit's on the field `year` and I was wondering if it was possible to have a string with a value `2017` and only inserting `17` when I press a button.

I have tried to use the `CONTAINS` property to check if it only has numbers, but now I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: Most likely you can use the 'Validating' event to enforce and rules you like. You need to add a tag further defining your environment e.g. WinForms or WPF or ???

Comment: Never use 2-digit dates.

Comment: In this case i must have a 2 digit value, because in my country the year of cars are measured in 2 digits, for example Month\Year. If so, you would have 04\17. Hope it explained how I want this to be.

Comment: @rheitzman I'm currently using winforms. This textbox will have a concat with the month, so the user doesn't enter the data wrong according to the license plate format in my country. thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd still use 'Validating' even given all the high tech answers below - hook both controls to the same event and use sender.name for logic flow. When both are present try to parse to a date, on success insert the two digit values back into the appropriate boxes or inform the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex.

```
Private Function returnLastTwo(input As Integer) As Integer
    Dim matchYearString As String = "(?:(\d\d)(?:(\d\d))?)"
    Dim output As Integer
    If CStr(input).Length = 4 Then
        output = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(CStr(input), matchYearString).Groups(2).Value
    ElseIf CStr(input).Length = 2 Then
        output = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(CStr(input), matchYearString).Groups(1).Value
    Else
        Throw New Exception("Check input")
    End If
    Return output
End Function
```

Comment: By this means, your answer would be nice but not applied because I don't want it to tell the user that he is wrong, but to simply correct his input if needed. I think by the complexity of this answer I will not be using it in this case, but it's certainly a good answer. Tested and it's working absolutely fine! Thanks in advance for your response!

Comment: @TiagoTurella you should accept the answer that worked for _you_.

Comment: @Tiago Turella If you are absolutely certain that only 2 or 4 characters are passed like 17 or 2017 then you can simply get rid of the else portion of if.

Comment: @bugs I've tryied everyone of those answers and all of them seem to work just fine. That's why i accepted everyone's answers, so you can have multiple ideas on a near future.

Comment: @EuX0 Yeah but since this one is more complex to understand, I'll stick with the simplest ones. But it's still a good way to make the exact same thing I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string/substring concept;

```
Module DateSplit
    Sub Main()
      Dim literal As String = "2017"
      Dim substring As String = literal.Substring(2)
      Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", substring)
   End Sub
End Module
```

I did not test this code but should output 17

Another approach would be casting your date as a string and create a char array, then you can have access to the element and convert them back to numbers if you like

```
Dim dateToSplit As Integer = 2017
Dim strDate As String = dateToSplit.ToString()

Dim charArr() AS Char = strDate.ToCharArray()
```

Comment: I see there Console.Writeline, by that mean you made this for console application. But I'll try it and change your answer if it's not exactly what winforms uses. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It is not really relevant what you do with the substring after you achieve the split, i only included the console output so you can see if the result is what you want. its entirely your business but i would not split the date and use 2 digit dates unless i really have to...

Comment: In my case I really need it. As I said, in my country the license plate if filtered by 2 digit year and 2 digit month. If so, I have 2 textboxes regarding both of the variables and after that I would CONCAT both of them to look like this MM\YY.

Comment: Would you just mind editing your answer and remove the console.writeline(...) and inserting this piece of code? It worked as I wanted! Thank you so much for the help. "TextBox.Text = substring"

Comment: @UlugToprak it does output 17. Tiago, `Console.WriteLine` writes to the Output window. You can see this in one of you tabs when debugging.

Comment: Since I'm still learning the structure of visual studio, I couldn't see it, but now it works fine! Thanks to all of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your user enters a date like this: `01/01/2017`, into the textbox:

```
dim dateFromTextbox = yourTextbox.Text ' ==> 01/01/2017
dim lastTwoDigits = Right(dateFromTextbox, 2)  ' ==> 17
```

Comment: `"Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Right As Integer"`. Gives me this error on `Right`property

Comment: @TiagoTurella in this case you would need to look at `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(dateFromTextbox, 2)` to fix that error. To be honest his is very much outdated and there are better methods to use

Comment: It's still an answer and I will validate it as a good one. Since it works fine too! Thanks in advance @Nicholas V.

Comment: @TiagoTurella no problem. Quite a small explanation by me, I admit. Really just wanted to highlight the `Right()` function that is available to you in vb.net. Good luck!